# MERN deployment to Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, mern

I'm having a really hard time figuring out how to deploy my app to heroku. Im new to all of this so I've tried different ways and following different tutorials but I just can't seem to find out how to do it.

This is my github repo:
https://github.com/solecity/card-deck-manager-app/tree/main

And in my logs from heroku I'm getting different errors:

```
2021-07-14T12:22:33.592361+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
```

---

```
Starting process with command `node index.js`
2021-07-14T12:25:08.838023+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
2021-07-14T12:25:08.838048+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2021-07-14T12:25:08.838048+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-07-14T12:25:08.838049+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-07-14T12:25:08.838049+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/index.js'
```

---

```
2021-07-14T12:27:16.812794+00:00 app[web.1]: Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'express' imported from /app/server/index.js
```

If anyone could shed some light on how I can fix this it will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

as the error states, you need to provide a start script in your package.json
apparently this is what heroku tries to runs. (error 1)
And if it doesn't find it, it runs something like node index.js (error 2)

also, you have not registered express in your dependencies in the main package.json so heroku doesn't install it. (error 3)

I'm not very used to heroku, but i think you should create 2 separate projects, and register them separately in heroku. that way he would find onlythe appropriate package.json and run.

Comment: Hi. thank you for your reply. I have a start script both in my client folder as well in my server folder

Comment: @Mari There is no start script in https://github.com/solecity/card-deck-manager-app/blob/main/package.json Also put ```web: npm start``` in Procfile, and remove other Procfiles. And create a single package.json (and lock file) at the base. Also avoid mixing `npm` and `Yarn`. You project contains both `package-lock.json` and `Yarn.lock`